# How to set environment variables with different values for each subdomain on Tomcat 7?

Tags: database, hibernate, configuration, tomcat7

I am trying to use environment Variables to set my Hibernate config database parameters for the same app running on different sub-domains on the same server.

Forexample :

1- www.xxx.com -> dbname=xxx_live

2- dev.xxx.com -> dbname=xxx_dev

And then in my Java app I want to get the environment variable of current subdmoain's and set it as hibernate config parameter.

I understood that I can get environment variables as follows from inside the app:

```
      Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
      cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", 
      System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
```

If I can set the same variable with different values for different subdomains then I can use this code to get and set hibernate configuration parameters.

Question is "How can I do it?"

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42643738/what-are-the-good-ways-to-configure-database-connection/42648095#42648095

Comment: This looks like it is used only for one database connection string on one tomcat instance. As I have mentioned in my question I do need 2 or more database connection parameters set based on sub-domain which is currently called. If I am mistaken please elaborate.

Comment: You can define many datasources in context.xml with different Resources names.Just need use that datasource in your db configuration file.

Comment: Using different parameter names in tomcat context.xml is not different then using different values inside the hibernate configuration file.Why? Because in any case I have to define which parameter to use on DEV sever before WAR creation. It is not solving the case I am working on.